# Forcing buffer overflow for Understanding

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I'm attempting to understand the concept of a buffer overflow and I'm having trouble computing how much data to stuff into the stack so it overflows correctly. Suppose I'm given some code (this is not my code, and yes it is from a class, but this isn't a graded assignment): 
**The goal is to get bar to be executed**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo(char *s) {
    char buf[4]; 
    strcpy(buf, s); 
    printf("You entered: [%s]", buf);
    fflush(stdout);
}

void bar() {
  printf("\n\nWhat? I was not supposed to be called!\n\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s some_string", argv[0]);
    return 2;
  }
  foo(argv[1]);
  return 0;    
}
```

When I disassemble bar I get the start address of bar:

```
(gdb) disas bar
Dump of assembler code for function bar:
   0x000000000040062d <+0>: push   %rbp
```

I was told that there needs to be 28 bytes of data stuffed into the buffer, and the last 4 bytes, need to be `\x2d\x06\x04\x00`. Where do you get 24 bytes to know how much random data to stuff.

Generally, and what i'm most interested in, is how to generalize and figure this out for any problem.

**How do you compute the number of bytes needed to fill the stack frame and then overwrite the return address of the function?**

Note: This is written in C, and compiled with GCC 4.4.7

Comment: This exercise would be safer if you did it in Java, C# or some other managed language instead of C.  Forcing a stack to overflow in C is not something I'd do deliberately.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm learning about cyber security, so I need to understand this. I understand that this isn't deliberately done.

Comment: @RobertHarvey sometimes we have to be brave programmers :)

Comment: You don't need a Stack Overflow for that.  You just need a buffer overrun.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow

Comment: Your are apparently mixing "stack overflow" and "buffer overrun/overflow exploit". "Stack overflow" has nothing to do with executing code that is not supposed to be executed.

Comment: @AnT Apparently so. I was unaware of the difference.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thank you for clarifying. I still am unsure of how to do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a single piece of C code, you can get different results.

```
void foo(char *s) {
    char buf[4]; 
    strcpy(buf, s); 
    printf("You entered: [%s]", buf);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The compiler may output

```
 ADD SP, 4   // space for buf
 PUSH SP-12  // address of string 's'
 PUSH SP-8   // address of SP (4 + space for s)
 call strcpy
 push literal_You_entered
 push SP-8
 call printf
 ...
```

Or it may want to have a stack frame.

```
PUSH Frame
MOVE SP, Frame
ADD SP, 4  // space for buf
....
```

Or it may need to save registers

```
PUSH Frame
MOVE SP, Frame
PUSH Reg1
PUSH Reg2
ADD SP, 4  // space for buf
```

This can be based on the optimization setting for the compiler.  In each case this moves the value around.

Try a magic buffer like `'\x01\x02\x03\x04\.....\xfe\xff'`.

The segmentation fault you get should show you where the important bytes are. Access violation at 0x08090a0b would describe which bytes were the return.

Overwriting the frame pointer (FP) means you can modify the behavior in the calling function, which may also help you.

Answer (score -1):

**How do you compute the number of bytes needed to fill the stack frame and then overwrite the return address of the function?**

You do it by learning the layout of the stack frame in the architecture that you're trying to exploit, and how the compiler places variables into the stack frame. 28 bytes happens to be the difference between the location of the first variable and the return address in the stack frame of the particular architecture you're using.

Comment: You have stated the obvious. I'm trying to figure out how to compute the number of bytes between the variable and the return address. Why is it 24 bytes in this case?

Comment: It's not something you compute, it's just something you find out. It's just the way it is in a particular stack frame layout.

Comment: If you had a copy of the structure declaration for the stack frame, you could use `offsetof` to calculate it.